# Equalizers don't exist in Rel.

Tags: category-theory

I suppose that there are equalisers in the category of relations Rel.

It contradicts to https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Rel :

"... order-relation $'\leq' \; \subseteq \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\}$ can’t be split. **It follows that it can’t have (co)equalisers.**"

I agree that leq is not split.

But empty relation between every two objects always exists!
So (especially when one or both of relations $f$ and $g$ are not functions) then every set(which is object in Rel) is an equaliser.

Empty set is always apex of one of the cones.
 "Empty relation" $ = \emptyset \subset \emptyset = A \times \emptyset =$ "set of relations between $A$ and empty set"

But, of course, not all sets are isomorphic. So my statement cannot be true. Where is my mistake?

I used definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equaliser_(mathematics)):

*"The equaliser consists of an object $E$ and a morphism $eq : E → X$ satisfying $f\circ eq=g\circ eq$, and such that, given any object $O$ and morphism $m : O → X$, if $f\circ m=g\circ m$, then there exists a unique morphism $u : O → E$ such that $eq\circ u=m$."*

Comment: This is really unclear. What, exactly, do you think would imply all sets are isomorphic? Are you claiming every set is an equalizer of the empty relation and...something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misreading; by saying "A category $\mathcal{C}$ doesn't have [(co)limits of a given type]", what one means is that there exists a diagram of the given type that fails to have a (co)limit.

That is, such a statement is the negation of the assertion that every diagram of the given type has a (co)limit.

For many types of diagrams, you are always guaranteed that a nonempty category has *some* instances of the diagram that have (co)imits; e.g. the constant diagram (all objects the same, all morphisms identities) often works.

---

From your comments, I think you're claiming that, in **Rel**, the empty set is an equalizer of the two morphisms $\leq$ and $1_{\{0,1\}}$.

Letting $e$ be the empty relation $\{\} \to \{0,1\}$, it is indeed true that $\leq \circ e = 1_{0,1} \circ e$. But that does not imply that $e$ is the equalizer!

To wit, $\leq \circ \leq = 1_{0,1} \circ \leq$, so if $e$ was the equalizer, there would exist a unique morphism $p : \{0,1\} \to \{ \}$ such that $\leq = e \circ p$.

However, the only morphism $p : \{0,1\} \to \{\}$ is the empty relation, and $e \circ p$ is not the relation $\leq$.

Comment: Thx for try. I am not misreading here. I just didn't found an example of pair of two morphisms which have no equalizer. I suppose that initial object is always(in Rel at least) an apex of some cone and sometimes is a limit.

Comment: @First: You were given an example: a nonsplit idempotent. (the equalizer and coequalizer of the idempotent and the identity are both a splitting of the idempotent)

Comment: Counterexample to what you said in parethesis, @Hurkyl. Let idempotent be $pr_{false} = \lambda(x:Bool).false : Bool \rightarrow Bool$, and $id_{Bool} = \lambda(x:Bool).x : Bool \rightarrow Bool$. Equalizer of $(pr_0, id_2)$ is the $(Terminal, \lambda(s:Terminal).false)$. It is neither section nor retraction of the $pr_{false}$.

Comment: @FirstLast: Let $e$ be the stated equalizer, and $!$ be the unique map $Bool \to Terminal$. Then $e! = pr_{false}$ and $!e = 1$.

Comment: My delusion (which led to asking question) was "Let f,g: C(a,b). Then all equalizers of f and g must be isomorphic in C.". They are isomorphic in category $id_C \downarrow F$, where F is functor from free quiver category to C.

Comment: @FirstLast: I misunderstood your previous comment as alleging a counterexample in **Set**. I think you are claiming that the empty set (and the empty relation) is an equalizer of $\leq$ and $1_{\{0,1\}}$? That's false, as you can immediately see by grinding through the proof that the equalizer gives a splitting. I've updated my answer.